# Як правильно: майнер чи майнінгіст?

Tags: значення-слів

Якщо за аналогією до окуліст, дезинфекціоніст, лінгвіст та ін., тобто слова, що мають суфікс [-іст](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky), який означає (у пункті № 56. є відсилання до -ист):

> 44. -ист, -иста, -іст на означення носія **професії, вмілости, або приналежности людини до чогось** (тут спалися два наростки український -ист і чужомовний -іст: бандурист (старіша форма бандуриста), цимбалист (-иста, -истий), басиста і деякі інші, але тепер здебільшого цей наросток вживається як чужомовний, отже то як -ист, то як -іст: юрист, артист..., спеціяліст..., навіть україніст, боротьбіст...

За цією аналогією мало би бути "майнінгіст". Однак усюди натрапляю на слово "майнер". Наприклад, у статті ["Майнер як професія, або як заробити гідні гроші в кризу"](https://ua.112.ua/ekonomika/mainer-iak-profesiia-abo-iak-zarobyty-hidni-hroshi-v-kryzu-307700.html).

**То як тоді правильно: майнер чи майнінгіст?**

До речі, йдеться про людину-майнера, яка займається майнінгом, а не про власне програму.

Comment: Але ж ніде не сказано, що це єдиний суфікс для цієї мети. Ми ще маємо *камен**яр*** (казкар, кухар тощо), *крав**ець*** (мовознавець, продавець тощо), *комбайн**ер*** (гравер, ліфтер тощо), *звар**ник*** (священик, мандрівник тощо; зокрема *зварюв**альник*** (шліфувальник, посівальник тощо)), *паст**ух***, *випробув**ач*** (добувач, командувач тощо) тощо.

Comment: але "майнер" і "майнінгіст" можна сказати, а от "казкар" і "казкарист", "кравець" і "кравіст" та под. - ні. От вчора задумалася над майнінгом) можливо, ті 2 слова, про які питаю, лише формами будуть? Не можу дати відповіді собі на запитання це.

Comment: Чому не можна сказати «казкіст»? (Незвично (так не кажуть), але можливо (можна створити неологізм), по-моєму.) (Просто до запозичених слів, мені здається, більше пасують запозичені суфікси, а до власних — власні; але «-ер» і «-іст» однаково запозичені.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Правильно **майнер**, і на це є кілька міркувань.

1. В англ. мові **miner** - новотвір, що зазнав упливу неморфологічного словотвору. Поясню: первісно це слово означало професію шахтаря (без подробиць, бо там ще були значення по справі видобутку), а потім стало означати видобувача біткоїнів.

> **miner**
>
> 1. A person who works in a mine.
>
>    1.1 A person who obtains units of a cryptocurrency by running computer processes to solve specific mathematical problems.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/miner)

Зазначимо собі з цього те, що англ. **miner** - повноцінне слово в мові-джерелі, а не, скажімо, морфема, яку треба доповнювати укр. суфіксами. Слово зайшло повним комплектом - форма+значення.

2. **Майнер** - слово, запозичене з англ. у двох значеннях особи і програми (+ програма-вірус), не має омонімів в укр. мові, тому нема потреби відрізняти майнера зі сфери криптовалют від якогось іншого майнера. Зміна суфікса -ер на інший немотивована.

*Колись була спроба перекласти назву особи, що професійно варить каву, бариста як кав'яр, але в укр.мові вже є кав'яр в значенні рибної ікри, так само як і кавник і кав'ярник. Тому лишився бариста, як мені відомо.*

3. За бажанням, можна зробити кальку з англ. і перекласти назву особи, яка займається видобутком біткоїнів. Очевидно, що це не буде шахтар, оскільки це слово активно вживане на позначення особи-гірника. Якщо є бажання, можна використовувати лексеми "видобувач", "добувач", які, втім, позначені як розмовні в словнику, але це не завадить їхньму використанню. Можна погратися в словотвір і запропонувати "криптодобувач" чи щось таке, але це окреме питання.
4. Процес засвоєння запозичених слів поступовий, утім сьогодні через стрімкий розвиток сфери криптовалют його терміни засвоїлись в рекордний строк. Зверніть увагу, що **майнер** - форма, що поводиться в укр.мові як іменник чоловічого роду ІІ відміни і має вже всі необхідні закінчення для зручного обігу в мовленні. Фонемний склад слова також зручний для вимови.
5. Не правильною видається спроба ділити запозичене слово **майнер** на корінь майн- і суфікс -ер, бо в морфології запозичене слово вважається неподільним морфом (іноді зветься чистою основою), незалежно від його здатності приєднувати відмінкові закінчення.

> В українській мові є корені, які засвідчені одним словом (5 тисяч, 7
>   тисяч). Це переважно запозичені слова: какаду, фрау, алло, біфштекс

[Кореневі та афіксальні морфеми](http://studopedia.com.ua/1_137632_korenevi-ta-afiksalni-morfemi-zagalna-harakteristika.html)

Якби ми тут намагалися утворити засобами нашої мови слово на позначення особи від англ. запозиченя **майн**, то, мабуть, була би потреба обирати доцільний суфікс. Але ситуація геть інша. Слово **майн** не зайшло в український ужиток взагалі, тож маємо засвоювати майнер і майнінг окремо від їхнього англ. кореня.

Отже, **майнер** має всі шанси лишитися в такій формі.

Comment: Wow, про баристу — чудова історія, дякую!